# How do I subtract a variable with a float number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

e.q. I say that grade is 1.9 and I want it to subtract with 0.4 here is my code:

```
grade = input()
float(grade)

new_grade = grade - 0.4
print(new_grade)
```

Where is my mistake? I tried to convert the 0.4 to a float variable but it doesn't help.
And it gives me this error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Comment: float is not in place you need to re-assign `grade = float(input())`

Answer (score 3):

`float(grade)` does nothing useful on its own. `float` does the conversion, returns the number, then throws away the result because you didn't say what you wanted it to do with it.

You need to reassign it back to `grade`:

```
grade = float(grade)
```